# Android Studio - destroying when not connected to debugserver

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, java-native-interface

So I've started to create an application **with some native C++ code** in Android Studio. My phone is **Realme 8i**.
I've deployed my app to this phone. Everything works great until I try to debug my app.
When I'm launching debugging, I can even hit a breakpoint and see some variables in debug window. But after few seconds, **connection to my phone breaks and my app is instantly crashing**.
This is a very simple app for now, so it shouldn't crashing like that.

The only message from debug window in Adnroid Studio I'm getting is this one:

```
Debugger attached to process 29096
destroying when not connected to debugserver

Process finished with exit code 22
```

And here is a log from logcat (everything with warning level or greater):

```
2022-11-27 13:57:49.724 29568-29568/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 W/ActivityThread: Application com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
2022-11-27 13:57:51.631 29568-29584/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
2022-11-27 13:57:57.787 29568-29568/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 E/ANR_LOG: >>> msg's executing time is too long
2022-11-27 13:57:57.787 29568-29568/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 E/ANR_LOG: Blocked msg = { when=-8s145ms what=110 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{3d00b62 com.acme.acmecorptestapp02}} } , cost  = 8083 ms
2022-11-27 13:57:57.787 29568-29568/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 E/ANR_LOG: >>>Current msg List is:
2022-11-27 13:57:57.788 29568-29568/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <1> = { when=-8s144ms what=9999 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H }
2022-11-27 13:57:57.790 29568-29568/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <2> = { when=-8s142ms what=159 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=ClientTransaction LaunchActivityItem,ResumeActivityItem }
2022-11-27 13:57:57.792 29568-29568/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <3> = { when=-8s141ms what=159 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=ClientTransaction TopResumedActivityChangeItem, }
2022-11-27 13:57:57.793 29568-29568/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <4> = { when=-8s124ms what=0 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H callback=com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl }
2022-11-27 13:57:57.794 29568-29568/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <5> = { when=-7s809ms what=149 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.os.BinderProxy@2d8e4f3 }
2022-11-27 13:57:57.794 29568-29568/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <6> = { when=-7s124ms what=0 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H callback=android.app.-$$Lambda$ActivityThread$A4ykhsPb8qV3ffTqpQDklHSMDJ0 }
2022-11-27 13:57:57.794 29568-29568/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 E/ANR_LOG: >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
2022-11-27 13:57:57.927 29568-29659/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 E/QT: [QT]file does not exist
2022-11-27 13:57:58.244 29568-29568/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManager: sInstance is null, start a new sInstance
2022-11-27 13:57:58.801 29568-29568/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 W/mecorptestapp0: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-11-27 13:57:58.802 29568-29568/com.acme.acmecorptestapp02 W/mecorptestapp0: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

So I did some more testing and it turns out my issue is not really caused by having C++ code in my project. The issue was caused by setting **breakpoint in the wrong place in code**. It was set in **onCreate** in the main class. Moving breakpoint to another line in my code solved the issue (in this case to **onClick** function).

It's sad than I can't set a breakpoint wherever I want, because of this weird issue...
If I'll find a better solution, I will edit this answer.

EDIT: It also works fine on the emulator **Pixel 2 XL** in Android Studio.
I still don't know why it doesn't work on real phone...